# Integrating duktape with android ndk

Tags: android-ndk, duktape

I'm trying to integrate duktape with android jni. My jni's android.mk is pretty standard:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := mynativelib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mynativelib.cpp ductape.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

When I try ty compile my native project I get this error:

```
In file included from jni/duktape.h:174:0,
             from jni/mynativelib.cpp:3:
jni/duk_config.h:840:43: fatal error: exception: No such file or directory 
              #include <exception>  /* std::exception */
```

Error is referring to these lines in duk_config.h

```
#if defined(DUK_F_CPP)
#include <exception>  /* std::exception */
#endif
```

So should I use configure.py with some specific flags or fix android.mk...?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like writing a question helps brain to come up with an answer. As a background I'm investigating usage of same script in several platforms and I noticed that exception.h is included in windows platform and therefore I believe it is good to keep similar approach on android also. I added these flags to application.mk and it seems to work.

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -fexceptions
```